# NSArray empty with filteredArrayUsingPredicate ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

i have a little problem with "predicate"

i have NSArray (datesArray) which is composed to :

```
(
"2011-11-30",
"2011-11-28",
"2011-11-25"
)
```

and another NSArray (leadsArray) which composed to :

```
(
{
    "date_deadline" = "2011-11-30";
    name = "test1";
};
{
    "date_deadline" = "2011-11-28";
    name = "test2";
};
{
    "date_deadline" = "2011-11-25";
    name = "test3";
};
{
    "date_deadline" = "2011-11-28";
    name = "test4";
};
)
```

then i do that :

```
NSString *date = [datesArray objectAtIndex:section];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date beginswith %@", date];
NSArray *leads = [leadsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

return [leads count];
```

But my NSAraay (leads) is empty.

I do that to know the "numberOfRowsInSection".

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

As the key for the dates in your dictionary is "date_deadline" it should at least read

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date_deadline beginswith %@", date];
```

In any case consider if you needs `beginswith` or can test for equal and if you need to store strings for dates or can use `NSDate` objects.

Comment: OK i forgot that :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Great :-) You might consider marking this question answered (check mark below the vote indicator), Thanks :-)